# MonoDroid EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: web-services, xamarin.android, slsvcutil

I'm calling a web service using client code that I generated using Microsoft's slsvcutil. No matter what call I make, I'm getting an EndpointNotFoundException. Stack trace is below. The service is running on my local machine. I'm able to successfully make identical calls from a MonoTouch application using the same generated client code and the same web service.

I'm running 
Mono for Android 4.2.6
Monotouch 5.9.9.4
Mono 2.10.9

Anyone else seeing this?

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: A system exception has occurred. --->              System.Exception: Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable) ---> System.Exception: Network is unreachable
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+<BeginProcessRequest>c__AnonStorey7.<>m__1 (IAsyncResult r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequestAsyncResult.WaitEnd () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.EndRequest (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been the result of a networking configuration.

The difference that seems to have allowed the MonoTouch application to work where Android did not was that I had the Android application running on a device (connecting to the web service over the network) where the MonoTouch application was running from a simulator on the same machine as the web service.